# How to remove/uninstall item templates in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, xna, uninstallation

I have an item template that I did wrong and want to delete. I deleted the zip file from the output location and ran devenv /installvstemplates and devenv /setup and when I opened VS and tried to add a new item it was still there. stranger still, I can still use it and create copies of the file, so it must exist somewhere. Is there somewhere that visual studio stores the files after being installed that I need to delete? I also cant change the template, it stays the same no matter what I do.

Edit: If it makes a difference I am using XNA GS 4.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete bad Visual Studio templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789095/how-can-i-delete-bad-visual-studio-templates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out what was happening. For some reason, when VS 2010 installed the templates it copied the zip file to my old 2008 folder. I can't imagine why it would do this but I've put it out there for anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

There are several places the Visual Studio might store a template.  Deleting the `.zip` file from any of the locations below should remove it from the list:

> - `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions`
> - `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\    -> ProjectTemplatesCache_{xx}`
> - `%UserProfile%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates`

If the Template was installed via an extension, you can clear it out from the top directory above, or you can follow the [official instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293639(v=vs.100).aspx):

> `Tools` -> `Extension Manager` -> `Installed Extensions` -> `Templates` -> `YourTemplate` -> `[Uninstall|Disable]`

Answer (score 1):

Because the duplicate question is *really* about Visual Studio 2008 (although it contains answers for 2010), I decided to also post the answer for Visual Studio 2010 (found in a comment).

You can find custom templates at the following location:

> C:\Users[user]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates

Delete the zip files and they should be removed from Visual Studio.

Comment: The folder is empty on my hard drive, there are no zip or vstemplate files in that folder. :(

Comment: This doesn't work for me, they still appear in the add new dialogue

Comment: I have now deleted all the template files from all caches and personal user templates and visual studio is still showing all of them. I'm pretty sure that it's not refreshing the cache properly.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use **VS 2019** or **VS 2022**, you could also try this:

```
dotnet new --uninstall <PATH|NUGET_ID>
```

It works for me in **VS 2019** and **VS 2020** to uninstall **Avalonia** templates. Maybe it will work for older VS   versions, but I haven't tried.

### Description

The `dotnet new --uninstall` command uninstalls a template package at the `PATH` or `NUGET_ID` provided. When the `<PATH|NUGET_ID>` value isn't specified, all currently installed template packages and their associated templates are displayed. When specifying `NUGET_ID`, don't include the version number.

### Examples

Uninstall the **Avalonia** templates

```
dotnet new --uninstall Avalonia.Templates
```

From [MicrosoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-uninstall)