# Doubled project templates in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xna

[image]

So I installed XNA Game Studio 4.0 on Visual Basic 2013 Ultimate, but then I saw XNA 4.0 Refresh. I installed it as I thought it would replace the previous one but it didn't. Now I have 2 of each project templates... I need help with removing the copies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete bad Visual Studio templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789095/how-can-i-delete-bad-visual-studio-templates)

Comment: Yes, I figured I'd need to delete and re-install it myself... Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried to uninstall XNA and then reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, I figured I'd need to delete and re-install it myself... Thanks anyways.